# Android: Get token of authenticated account

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication

I have android app comunicating with api on remote server. I want to make user authentication via google account. I know there's many pages/questions about this topic, but I kind of couldn't figured out which method I need to use.

What I want is, when user registers with his google account, his account will be authenticated and then I want Google to generate some auth token, which is specific for the app and users account. This token should never change, because it should be used on api server to authenticate user.

Do I need to link my app somehow to Google AppEngine or is there any simple solution which I'm not seeing? Or is this method of authenticating completly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might be a bit wrong. Cause No one (Not even the Google apps on android) ever get a non expiring token. You Need to save the refresh token and the current token. and after every hour you need to refresh the token using refresh token. And you are good to go (If I have understood your question :P). I would suggest if you already own a server better host the back-end there else GAE works just fine. I hope it helps :)